# What's the difference between the following resample methods for manipulating OHLC data?

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

```
ohlc_dict = {'openB':'first', 'highB':'max', 'lowB':'min', 'closeB': 'last'}
```

What's the difference between this:

```
df.resample('1W', base=1).agg(ohlc_dict)
```

and this:

```
df.resample('1W', how=ohlc_dict, base= 1, closed='left', label='left')
```

I am trying to manipulate 1 hour OHLC data into 4 hours, daily, weekly etc. At first, [I thought I should use the 1st one according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944436/converting-ohlc-stock-data-into-a-different-timeframe-with-python-and-pandas). Then I found out about the 2nd one, and they both should reach the same result. But I found out that they actually have 2 different results. I got the correct result from the 2nd method though. Can someone explain the difference between the two? Thanks.

Comment: The second one is deprecated. It won't work in future releases. As for the different results: please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @ayhan  What's the new correct code for that if I want to achieve the same result?

Comment: That would require you to provide a [MCVE], please.