# Converting Intraday OHLCV Data to Higher Timeframes via pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have intraday OHLCV data on several coins on the 4H timeframe that I want to convert to the daily timeframe. I am new to Python so I don't know where to proceed next(my focus right now is studying sql).
So here's the sample of the dataframe:

| Pair | Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTCUSDT | 2021-06-30 08:00:00 | 35000 | 36100 | 34000 | 35500 | 10000000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 12:00:00 | 35505 | 37000 | 35400 | 35600 | 12000000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 16:00:00 | 35650 | 42000 | 32000 | 41000 | 20000000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 20:00:00 | 41100 | 41500 | 38000 | 39000 | 15000000 |
| ETCUSDT | 2021-06-30 08:00:00 | 3500 | 3800 | 3200 | 3300 | 1000000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 12:00:00 | 3350 | 3600 | 3100 | 3200 | 730000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 16:00:00 | 3270 | 4000 | 3200 | 3800 | 2000000 |
|  | 2021-06-30 20:00:00 | 3900 | 4300 | 3800 | 4200 | 3000000 |

So for the dataframe, I used "Pair" and "Date" as multiindex. There are over 300 pairs in the actual data. Tried searching for similar questions but unlike my question, the others had only one pair, or for those with multiple pairs, they don't have the OHLCV data. They just only have the close or mean price.

Here is the result I want:

| Pair | Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTCUSDT | 2021-06-30 | 35000 | 42000 | 32000 | 39000 | 57000000 |
| ETCUSDT | 2021-06-30 | 3500 | 4300 | 3100 | 4200 | 6730000 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting OHLC stock data into a different timeframe with python and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944436/converting-ohlc-stock-data-into-a-different-timeframe-with-python-and-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be better to create your own classes to feed the data to and manage the data (appending data to list within class so you know the open (first data point) and close (last data point), high and low are just max and min, volume is sum), but to keep within `pandas` you can calculate these individually after removing the time part of the `Date` field, then `concat` together at end.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x[:10])

# Open
o = df.groupby(['Pair', 'Date']).agg('first')['Open']

# Close
c = df.groupby(['Pair', 'Date']).agg('last')['Close']

# High
h = df.groupby(['Pair', 'Date']).agg('max')['High']

# Low
l = df.groupby(['Pair', 'Date']).agg('min')['Low']

# Volume
v = df.groupby(['Pair', 'Date']).agg('sum')['Volume']

final_df = pd.concat([o, h, l, c, v], axis=1)
```

If converting to weekly timeframe, use this to parse dates in dataframe but use the same code to calculate OHLCV

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def convert_to_week(dt):
    d = datetime.strptime(dt[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
    d = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday()+1)
    return d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: convert_to_week(x))
```

Comment: Might need to reset the index if `Pair` and `Date` are apart of the index. `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Hi. How about if I want to convert it to a weekly timeframe

Comment: @jomx99 Just edited answer to show how to transform to weekly timeframes.